Scrapy get text returns just \r\n
I am scraping this url - the HTML looks like this:
<div class="col-12 col-lg-4 profile-practical-information tab-pane" id="Information" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="Information_head">
                            <section>
                                <h3>Types of sessions</h3>
                                <ul>
                                        <li>Face to Face - Long Term</li>
                                        <li>Face to Face - Short Term</li>
                                </ul>
                            </section>

I can get the content in Scrapy shell but it outputs with unwanted HTML tags:
In [1]: fetch('https://www.psychotherapy.org.uk/therapist/Lindsay-James-Wells-iAiuuAAC')
In [3]: response.css('.profile-practical-information section').get()
Out[3]: '<section>\r\n                                <h3>Types of sessions</h3>\r\n                                <ul>\r\n                                        <li>Face to Face - Long Term</li>\r\n                                        <li>Face to Face - Short Term</li>\r\n                                </ul>\r\n                            </section>'

If I ask for text only without the HTML tags:

In [4]: response.css('.profile-practical-information section::text').get()
Out[4]: '\r\n

Why does the output stop at \r\n ?
How can I get the content without the unwanted HTML tags?

Your selector picks the text content in the section node only. To obtain the text in child nodes probably the * selector and using the scrapy .getall() function on the selector instead could be more appropriate.
In [4]: response.css('.profile-practical-information section *::text').getall()
Out[4]: 
['\n                                ',
 'Types of sessions',
 '\n                                ',
 '\n                                        ',
 'Face to Face - Long Term',
 '\n                                        ',
 'Face to Face - Short Term',
 '\n                                ',
 '\n                            ']

You can then join the resulting list output using an appropriate separator and removing unwanted characters as applicable.
